# AngularJs reading angular expression

Tags: angularjs

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/studentinfo.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">

        <div id="header">
                    <h1>
                        <span class="black-text">School Management Site</span>
                    </h1>
        </div><!--header end-->
        <div id="topmenu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="school_home_page.jsp">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="student_Info_page.html">STUDENTS</a>

                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="class_info_.jsp">CLASS INFORMARION</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="login.jsp">LOGOUT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--topmenu end-->

        <div id="content">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div ng-controller="studentInfoController"  ng-init="getStudentsInfo()">
                    <form name="studentform" ng-submit="submitStudentForm(studentform.$valid)" novalidate>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h3>Student Form:</h3>
                            <h4 style="color: red;">{{errorModel.errorMessage}}</h4>



                            <label for="rollno" style="color: blue;">StudentRollNo:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rollno"
                                        name="studentRollNo" ng-model="student.studentRollNo" required
                                        placeholder="RollNo">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <span style="color: red"
                                        ng-show="studentform.studentRollNo.$error.required && submitted">
                                        StudentRollNo  is required.</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" style="color: blue;">StudentName:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="studentName"
                                        name="studentName" ng-model="student.studentName" required
                                        placeholder="StudentName">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <span style="color: red"
                                        ng-show="studentform.studentName.$error.required && submitted">
                                        StudentName  is required.</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" style="color: blue;">Address:</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="village"
                                    name="village" ng-model="student.village"
                                    placeholder="Village" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                 </div>
                 <br/>
                 <br/>

                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="districtName"
                                    name="districtName" ng-model="student.districtName"
                                    placeholder="DistrictName" >
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <span style="color: red"
                                    ng-show="studentform.districtName.$error.required && submitted">
                                    DistrictName is required. </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>

                     <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="state"
                                        name="state" ng-model="student.state" required
                                        placeholder="State">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <span style="color: red"
                                        ng-show="studentform.state.$error.required && submitted">
                                        StateName  is required.</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                 <br/>
                 <br/>

                 <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                 </div>
                    </form>
                    Total Number of Student:<label style="color: black">{{studentsData.length}}</label>
                        <table id="stuId" border="1" style="color: blue;">
                            <tr>
                                <th>StudentRollNo</th>
                                <th>StudentName</th>
                                <th>DELETE</th>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr ng-repeat="student in studentsData" style="color: black;">
                                        <td>
                                            {{student.studentRollNo}}
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            {{student.studentName}}

                                        </td>

                                        <td>

                 <input type="button" name="info" value="DeleteStudent" ng-click = "deleteStudent({{student.addresId}})">

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                        </table>    

                </div>                  
            </div>


        </div><!--content endss-->


    </div><!--container end-->          
</body>
```

when we are loading this page we are getting error
my error is
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=16&p3=deleteStudent(%7B%7Bstudent.addresId%7D%7D)&p4=%7Bstudent.addresId%7D%7D)
   at ib.equality (http://localhost:8080/SchoolSystem/angular/lib/angular.min.js:196:291)  
how can reslove this error

Comment: remove the `{{}}` inside `deleteStudent()` in the view

Comment: but i want to send a addresid using angular expression.and my all data in model studentsData. so  how can send my data. tell me

Comment: you don't need the `{{}}` . Scope functions will already evaluate scope variables passed to the function. `{{}}` is used for text output in view only

Comment: thanks my code is running.

Comment: i agree with you. but i want to send data from my jsp file to javascript file using angular. is there any way to send data.

Comment: I never used Abugular JS, but I've heard great things about it.